# inserting the result of a mongo db query in a new collection

Tags: mongodb

i want to store the result of a mongo db query in a new collection but i have this error : uncaught exception: can't save a DBQuery object.

this is my code :

```js
var com=db.comments.find({message: /http/ })   
db.com_filtre.insert(com);
```

the variable com isn't empty. when i try com.size(): i have 50 elements.

Answer (score 4):

The result of [`.find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is a "Cursor" and not a plain object. You either convert it via [`.toArray()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

```js
var com=db.comments.find({message: /http/ }).toArray()   
db.com_filtre.insert(com);
```

Or get a [singular object](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/):

```js
var com=db.comments.findOne({message: /http/ })
db.com_filtre.insert(com);
```

It depends if you want to insert "many" matches or a single document.

Answer (score 1):

find() method returns a cursor to the resultSet. hence u need to fetch the documents from the cursor as below :

```
 var cur = db.comments.find({message: /http/});
 while( cur.hasNext() )
  {
    db.com_filtre.insert( cur.next() );
  }
```